# Put Not Working to Update with Axios Mongoose

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mongoose, axios

I am trying to set up an edit feature to edit a post. Right now I am trying to update a specific post by ID and then I'll make it dynamic.

I can get axios to send the PUT request but I don't receive any indication that it is received on the router. Also the ID I have set it showing up correctly in the URL.

I'm not sure how to send the data over to the router so it can find the ID.

**Edit component**

```
function handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        axios ( {
            url: `/api/${props.data[0]._id}`,
            method: 'PUT',
           headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
            id: props.data[0]._id
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log(`data has been sent to the server from axios: ${props.data[0]._id}`)
        })
        .catch(() => {
            console.log('Data could not be sent from axios')
        })

    }
```

**Router**

```
 router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
      try {
    
        const updatedGratitude = await PostGratitude.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id)
    
        res.status(200).json(updatedGratitude)
    
      } catch (err){
    
        next(err)
    
    }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are editing a post then you should send the data in the request as well
like a title: "" and description: "" or something and in the in the router, you could write something like this :

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault()
axios({
    url: `/api/${props.data[0]._id}`,
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    data: {
        title: '',
        description: ''
    }
})
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

}

you need to pass the arguments as to what to update as well, here is an example of a code that I wrote

```
router.put('/updatentry/:id',fetchuser, async (req, res) => {
var success = false
try {
    const { title, description } = req.body
    let newentry = { title: title , description: description
     }
    

    let old_entry = await Journal.findById(req.params.id);
    if (!old_entry) {
        return res.status(404).send({ success, error: 'Not Found'})
    }
    
    const update_entry = await Journal.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { $set: newentry }, { new: true })
    return res.send(res: update_entry)
} catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send(error: 'Internal Server Error')
}

})
```

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. It looks like one of the main problems was that I was not setting "data" and "params" when sending. Also the content type I had set up did not allow me to get the body back as I was getting undefined. When I added what you put, I got the body back.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you forgot the update body on method. Try this:

`PostGratitude.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body)`

instead of :

`await PostGratitude.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id)`

Because mongoose can not know what to update :D